# add a matrix to a tibble

Tags: r, matrix, extract, tibble

I want to add a new column to an existing tibble, and each element of the new column is a matrix. Here is what I did,

Add it to the tibble `WY_reg` using `list`

```
WY_reg <- WY_reg %>%
           add_column(NewMat = list(Mat1, Mat2,Mat3) )
```

That indeed adds a new column. However, it seems that when I execute `WY_reg$NewMat[1]`, it returns a list, rather than a matrix, so that I cannot do usual matrix operations.

I also tried `as.matrix` but fails.

Is there any way I can put a new column and each element is a matrix? so that they can involve later operations? Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: can you try `WY_reg$NewMat[[1]]` ?

Comment: It works! Thanks! @markus

Comment: For context, does `list(Mat1,Mat2,Mat3)[1]` return a list or a matrix? It's the same thing, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272 is a good reference for it.